# Issue with Airflow dynamic tasks creation

Tags: python, airflow

I have created the following workflow which has dynamically added tasks. But Airflow is not able to add the `Task`, `Join` and `QT` nodes to the Dag. In the graph representation I can see only the `START` and the `END` nodes. Is there anything I am doing wrong here.

Thanks.

```
dag = DAG(
    'ddl_ver1',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *'
)


start_node = DummyOperator(task_id='ddl_start',
                        dag=dag)


end_node = DummyOperator(task_id='ddl_finish',
                        dag=dag)


 def create_qts(account_id):
    qts = []
    for i in range(7):
        qt = DummyOperator(task_id='ddl_qt_' + str(account_id) + "_" + str(i),
                      dag=dag)
        qts.append(query)

    return qts



def create_data_discovery_tasks(accounts):
    for account_id in accounts:
        task = DummyOperator(
            task_id='ddl_task_' + str(account_id),
            dag=dag)

        join = DummyOperator(
            task_id='ddl_join_' + str(account_id),
            dag=dag)

        qts = create_qts(account_id)

        for qt in qts:
            qt.set_upstream(task)
            qt.set_downstream(join)

        task.set_upstream(START)

        join.set_downstream(END)
```

Answer (score 0):

`create_qts` is never actually called the way it is.

Also need to call either `set_downstream` or `set_upstream` if you want to start at start, put the generated tasks in the middle, and then end at finish.

This will work fine (note the very last line):

```py
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime

dag = DAG(
    'ddl_ver1',
    schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
    start_date=datetime(2017,4,30)
)


start_node = DummyOperator(task_id='ddl_start',
                        dag=dag)


end_node = DummyOperator(task_id='ddl_finish',
                        dag=dag)


def create_qts(account_id):
    previous_qt = None
    for i in range(7):

        qt = DummyOperator(task_id='ddl_qt_' + str(account_id) + "_" + str(i),
                      dag=dag)

        if previous_qt:
            previous_qt.set_downstream(qt)
        else:
            start_node.set_downstream(qt)

        previous_qt = qt

    qt.set_downstream(end_node)

create_qts(123)
```